# How to call history/fc from a ZSH script

Tags: zsh

I am attempting to write a script for GeekTool that will show my last X (20) commands on my screen.

I can either display a file or use the output of a shell command (preferred).

The problem is that when I run the command from a script I get `~/bin/update_history_file.sh:fc:5: no such event: 0` as an error.

My script file is:

```
#!/bin/zsh --login
#history | tail -n 25 > /tmp/history.txt

export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history 
fc -l -20 -1
```

The `fc` command works if I run it from a shell; however if I run it from the script then it fails.  I think it has something to do with it not being able to read the history file, but have no confirmation of this.

I can not directly use the `.zsh_history` file as I use ZSH extended history and has embedded meta data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a `fc -R` to force reading the history file, and delete that `-1`

```
#!/bin/zsh --login
#history | tail -n 25 > /tmp/history.txt

export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history 
fc -R
fc -l -20
```

Comment: This was the exact problem... it wasn't clear to me that it must happen in two separate commands.  Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone else gets `fc -R: invalid option`, make sure your shebang line is `/bin/zsh` and not bash or sh.